# how to gray scale a picture in python using rgb?

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, grayscale

I'm writting a function (it has to be called into the main py file later where i take the rgb values, add them, and average them so to get a gray picture. Here is what i have so far:

```
def gray_scale(img,x,y): 
    pixel=img[x][y]
    r= pixel[0]
    g=pixel[1]
    b=pixel[2]
   return(r+g+b)/3
```

I have to call this function in my main file (I'm also having trouble with this because im not sure how to use the parameters. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Your function returns the grayscale value for the pixel (x, y) from the image. What exactly do you want to do? If you want to convert a RGB image to grayscale use ```grayscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(RGB_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)```

Comment: yes thats what im hoping to do. I think my professor wants us to grayscale by taking the average of all values however

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your question is how to use this function to convert an image to grayscale.

Firstly, in you main.py:

```
for x in range(img.shape[0]):
    for y in range(img.shape[1]):
        gray_pixel = gray_scale(img[x][y])
        grayscaled_image[x][y] = gray_pixel
```

Assuming that the shape attribute is supported by your image. If it is a Numpy array, it is.

The gray_scale function will look like this:

```
def gray_scale(pixel_value): 
    r = pixel[0]
    g = pixel[1]
    b = pixel[2]

    return (r + g + b) / 3
```

This is what is happening in the above code. Your main.py iterates over all pixels in the image. These pixels (each of which is an array containing the R, G and B values) are sent to the gray_scale function.

This function computes the gray scale value and returns it. This gray scaled value is stored in the gray_pixel variable.

Then this gray scaled pixel is inserted into the appropriate location in the grayscaled_image.

Obviously, the more optimized and easier way is to use OpenCV as @DinosaurMoritz pointed out, unless you have to implement your own.